# Kaye-Wong paper Theorem 6.5

Tags: logic, set-theory, proof-theory, peano-axioms

In the paper [On Interpretations of Arithmetic and Set Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1193667707) of Kaye and Wong they say that Theorem 6.5 (that PA can be interpreted in ZF-Inf*, that is, ZF plus every set is contained in a transitive closure and the negation of Inf) follows from Theorem 4.5 and Propositions 5.6 and 6.3. Why is that?

I think I can verify it for the semi-ring axioms ($\text{PA}^-$) without much trouble, but the induction axiom scheme becomes (right?):
$$ [ \, \forall y \,(\forall x \, ( \; ( p(x) < p(y) \to \varphi^{\mathfrak{b}}(x)) \to \varphi^{\mathfrak{b}}(y)) \, ] \to \forall y \, \varphi^{\mathfrak{b}}(y) $$
where $p(x) = \sum_{y\in x} \, 2^{p(y)}$. I'm not sure how to tackle that. Epsilon induction?

And what do Theorem 4.5 and Propositions 5.6 and 6.3 have to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to sketch the detail of their article.

First, Theorem 4.5 establishes that the ordinal interpretation $\mathfrak{o}$ ensures $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}$ interprets $\mathsf{PA}$. However, the ordinal interpretation is not *bijective*, in the sense that $\mathsf{ZF-Inf}$ does not prove $\forall x \operatorname{Dom}^\mathfrak{o}(x)$. In the case of ordinal interpretation, $\operatorname{Dom}^\mathfrak{o}(x)$ is equivalent to that $x$ is an ordinal, but not all sets are ordinals.

On the other hand, if $\mathfrak{o}$ has an inverse interpretation $\mathfrak{t}$, then $(\operatorname{Dom}^\mathfrak{o})^\mathfrak{t}(x)$ is equivalent to $x=x$. Hence $\operatorname{Dom}^\mathfrak{o}(x)$ is equivalent to $(x=x)^\mathfrak{o}$, and in the case of ordinal interpretation, this is just $x=x$.
Therefore there is no interpretation $\mathfrak{t}:\mathsf{ZF-Inf\to PA}$ such that $\mathfrak{o\circ t}$ is the identity interpretation $\mathsf{Id}_\mathsf{ZF-Inf}$.

This is the reason why Kaye and Wong introduce $\mathfrak{p}$: by composing $\mathfrak{o}$ with $\mathfrak{p}$, we can make the interpretation closer to 'bijective'. To achieve this, we have to ensure $\mathfrak{p}$ a bijective class function, and this is the role of Proposition 6.3.

Proposition 5.6 is about $\mathfrak{a}$, not $\mathfrak{b}$. However, it explains why we need to consider the existence of transitive closure as an axiom of a set-theoretic counterpart of $\mathsf{PA}$. I do not find any specific role of this proposition in the proof, but it *at least* gives how to motivate the statement of Theorem 6.5.

Lastly, your interpretation of the induction scheme is not correct. The correct interpretation should be
$$[\forall y (\forall x (\mathfrak{p}(x)<\mathfrak{p}(y))\to \phi(\mathfrak{p}(x))\to \phi(\mathfrak{p}(y))]\to \forall y \phi(\mathfrak{p}(y)).$$

(Interpretations might be confusing. This article suppresses some details.)

Then everything is clear: since $\mathfrak{p}(x)$ is an arbitrary *natural number* (or finite ordinals, if you prefer), we can see that the previous statement is another way to describe the induction scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As far as I understand interpretations they don't send elements to elements, but atomic formulas to atomic formulas (the notion in the paper is proof-theoretic not model-theoretic), so what you mean by _bijection_ is not entirely clear to me yet. Can you expand on your example why you can prove $(\forall x: x\text{ is an ordinal})^{\mathfrak{to}}$? Also shouldn't that be ${\mathfrak{ot}}$?

Comment: @Jori I will expand my answer a bit for the first question. For the second question, $\phi^\mathfrak{o\circ t}$is applying $\mathfrak{t}$ first and $\mathfrak{o}$ later, so it is $(\phi^\mathfrak{t})^\mathfrak{o}$.

Comment: I still don't understand you; what even is $\forall y \exists x [\mathfrak{o}(x) = y]$? You apply an interpretation to an _element_. I don't understand what you mean with  "ZF−Inf does not prove surjectivity "$\forall y \exists x [\mathfrak{o}(x) = y]$". Please clarify, because you're confusing me a lot ;)

Comment: @Jori Sorry, my hunch on interpretation is always model-theoretic, but our definition is not. I will fix it.

Comment: @Jori (and you were right on the composition of interpretation, and I have to withdraw my previous comment. It is still confusing to me.)

Comment: I think I get it, but your phrasing is a bit different from the paper: suppose there exists $t$ as an inverse to $o$, then $[ ( \forall x \, \text{Dom}(x) )^o ]^t$ is equivalent (over PA) to $\forall x \, \text{Dom}(x)$ (which is true). However the former is also equivalent to $(\forall x \, (x \in \text{Ord}) )^t$, but this must be false because $\forall x \, (x \in \text{Ord})$ is, hence: contradiction, a true statement cannot be equivalent to a false one. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Jori Yes, you can derive a contradiction in this way.